# Angular factory $resource returns no value

Tags: json, angularjs

I have recently downgraded my angular app from **1.3** to **1.2** as the client needs to support IE8.

My factory resource function was working in **1.3** but now the `$values` array is not seen in the returned **JSON** response.

Here is what the factory function looks like:

```
offersController.factory('Offer241GetAll', function ($resource, config) {
    return $resource(config.apiUrl + '/TwoForOne/GetAll');
});
```

And the controller that calls the method:

```
offersController.controller('offers241Controller', function ($scope, Offer241GetAll) {
    Offer241GetAll.get(function (data) {
        $scope.offers = data.$values;
    });
});
```

`data.$values` should contain an array but `data` only contains:

```
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
```

Strangely this `$http.get()` method works and I have confirmed that values are being sent by the API:

```
$http.get(config.apiUrl + '/TwoForOne/GetAll').then(function(r){
    $scope.offers = r.data.$values;
});
```

How can I continue to use my resource function like before in version **1.3**? 
Are there any differences to how this works in different versions of angular?

Comment: minus one for what exactly? If I can improve my question with additional code I can provide if needed...

Answer (score 0):

$http and $resource methods works differently.

$http get method returns a promise.

$resource method Offer241GetAll.get returns to you an object with promise and state of promise.
You can try something like this:

```
offersController.controller('offers241Controller', function ($scope, Offer241GetAll) {
Offer241GetAll.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.offers = data;
});
```

});

More about this you can [find here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Hey, I gave this a try but the same result was returned i.e the `$values` array is missing from the response. It is defiantly being sent by the API ive checked the response in Fiddler

Comment: Could you send a link to your Fiddler example?